# How can I make my header sticky and on top of everything?

Tags: css-position, sticky

I currently have my header sticky but of some reason it has an opacity. I want it to be relative and sticky but I can't assign both to the header.

This is what I have:

```
.header {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #007eb6;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the header supposed to be stuck to the top of the page at all times? Or is this a kind of table-header that needs to stick to the top of the table as you scroll it? Some further clarification and usage sample (HMTL) could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `z-index` property to stack your div on top of everything with the `position: sticky`,

if you mean that you want your header to scroll down with you when you're scrolling, then you're looking for `position: fixed`.

And for the opacity part, it's most likely your header is inside a div which has the `opacity` property, so check that as well or get your header div out of it.

Hope this helps.

```css
.header {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #007eb6;
  z-index: 99;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> header here</div>
<div>here's another content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you want to achieve, so I apologize if this isn't quite what you hope to find.

I tried this:

https://playcode.io/1038441

Here, you see 'Moo' has your styling, and it isn't transparent or translucent.  So, I suspect you have another style that's introducing that.  You might check to see what your element has inherited, or you might explicitly set your .header to have an opacity of 1 (.header{ opacity: 1;})

As you scroll the blathering text, it scrolls under the 'Moo' header, which is what sticky does.

It can be 'relative' in the sense that you could give a 'top' of 10px, and it will be offset from the top by 10px, but still 'sticking' to the location.